# Write correct SQL Query for:- i used query ? Data is coming from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I used query:-

```
select 
    employees.N, employees.ID, Date(Month) as m, count(*) as P,
    (FullOrHalfLeave) as FOH 
from 
    employees, leaveapplication, leaveapplicationdetails 
where 
    employees.ID = leaveapplication.ID 
    and leaveapplication.LeaveApplicationID = leaveapplicationdetails.Leave_Application_ID 
    and TypeOfLeave = 1 
    and LeaveStatus = 4 
    and employees.ID = 18 
group by 
    employees.ID,FOH 
order by 
    employee.N, FOH
```

I get a result like below:-

```
N       ID      m       P         FOH
--------------------------------------
A       18      1       8          1
A       18      1       3          2
A       18      4       6          1
A       18      5       3          1
A       18      5       1          2
A       18      6       3          2
A       18      9       1          1
A       18      9       4          2
```

I want result like this:

```
N       ID      m       Pad         FOH
----------------------------------------
A       18      1       9.5          -
A       18      4       6            -
A       18      5       3.5          -
A       18      6       1.5          -
A       18      9       3            -
```

Comment: -'s are in FOH column means in FOH column data doesnot matter

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Which database did you use? Because the syntax of specific sql commands can be difference to each other.

Comment: Mysql database well i dont know version of database

Comment: What's the logic for calculating the `Pad` values you're showing?

Comment: if FOH==1 then number=number and if FOH==2 then number=number/2

and yes Pad means P of first table

Comment: You don't need FOH returned, just do `select employees.N, employees.ID, Date(Month) as m, SUM(1 / FullOrHalfLeave) as P`

Comment: what is the logic behind using 1/FullOrHalfLeave

it will not give me my answer

Comment: database version is 4.3

Comment: in FOH for fulldayleave value is 1

and for halfdayleave value is 2

Comment: That is the logic, if you divide by `FOH` you get exactly the number you want. `1 day` for `FOH = 1` and `1/2 day` for `FOH = 2`. I'll post it as an answer, please try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need FOH returned, just do:

```
select employees.N, employees.ID, Date(Month) as m, SUM(1 / FullOrHalfLeave) as P
```

this way, if `FOH = 1` then you'll be counting one day and if `FOH = 2` you'll be counting half day.